# How open a messenger application with a static telephone number?

Tags: android, angularjs, android-intent

I´m trying to open my own messenger application(programming with Ionic and Angularjs) with a static telephone number, I can open my app from a webpage using the next intent:

**intent://host#Intent;scheme=mycoolapp;package=mypackage;end**

Now I want to open my application with a new intent but including a static telephone number just like this :

**intent://send/+mynumber#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end**

That example works fine with Whatsapp but if I change my intent with my app information:

**intent://send/+mynumber#Intent;scheme=mycoolapp;package=mypackage;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end**

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" 
android:versionName="0.0.1" package="mypackage" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" 
android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard
|screenSize|locale" 
android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" 
android:name="MainActivity" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">      
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="myhost" android:scheme="myscheme"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
    android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName" 
    android:value="@string/fb_app_name" />
    <activity 
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout
   |screenSize|orientation" android:label="@string/fb_app_name" 
   android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" 
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <receiver android:exported="false" 
     android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin
   .localnotification.TriggerReceiver" />
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name=
   "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClearReceiver" />
    <activity android:exported="false" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClickActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.TriggerReceiver" />
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClearReceiver" />
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.RestoreReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClickActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

That doesn´t work correctly. Do you know how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have an `<intent-filter>` that will handle `ACTION=SENDTO`? Probably not. Why did you add `action=android.intent.action.SENDTO` to the intent URL? Post your manifest please.

Comment: Thank you David, I added my manifest and I forgot to delete the action=android.intent.action.SENDTO to my intent URL.

Comment: Did removing the SENDTO action solve your problem? Or do you still need help?

Comment: I still need help, I change my Intent URL with this: intent://myhost/mynumber#Intent;scheme=myscheme=mypackage;end

Comment: This URL makes no sense. Did you copy/paste this exactly? Should be `scheme=myscheme;package=mypackage;`

Comment: Sorry I wrote bad my Intent , I have it in the next way:  intent://myhost/mynumber#Intent;scheme=myscheme;package=mypackage;en‌​d a

Comment: Is correct my android manifest?

Comment: Your manifest looks OK. I don't see anything wrong. sorry.